# Inserting element at start of linked list works in function, but on return from function the start point is NULL

Tags: c

I am trying to insert at the start of an empty linked list with this function:

```
void push(Node* node_to_insert, searchQueue* queue)
{
    searchQueue* elem_to_insert = (searchQueue*)malloc(sizeof(searchQueue));
    elem_to_insert->node = node_to_insert;
    if(queue_size == 0)
        elem_to_insert->next = NULL;
    else
        elem_to_insert->next = queue;
    queue = elem_to_insert;
    queue_size++;
}
```

During the execution of the function everything works as expected but upon return the pointer to the start of the list is NULL.

This is the code I use to call the function:

```
searchQueue* queue = (searchQueue*)malloc(sizeof(searchQueue));
push(start_node, queue);
```

I have also tried not allocating memory on initialisation of the list but I still get the same result.

Comment: In `queue = elem_to_insert;` you are overwriting the local *copy* of the variable passed as a function argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing a local copy of the pointer in `push`. That does not change the value of the pointer in the calling function.

I suggest changing the return type of `push` to `searchQueue*` and returning the new pointer.

```
searchQueue* push(Node* node_to_insert, searchQueue* queue)
{
  searchQueue* elem_to_insert = (searchQueue*)malloc(sizeof(searchQueue));
  elem_to_insert->node = node_to_insert;
  if(queue_size == 0)
    elem_to_insert->next = NULL;
  else
    elem_to_insert->next = queue;
  queue = elem_to_insert;
  queue_size++;

  return element_to_insert;
}
```

and in the calling function, use:

```
 queue = push(start_node, queue);
```